# RabbitMQ: routing messages to threads

Tags: ruby, rabbitmq, amqp

I have an application written in Ruby that has multiple threads that each send requests to remote AMQP endpoints. These threads are spawned from time to time when new tasks have to be run.

If I use temporary, exclusive queues per thread for sending responses to their requests, then it becomes easy to write the code to handle incoming messages in this Ruby service. The queues are deleted as soon as the associated channel is closed so they don't stick around after their purpose is over.

The alternatives I can think of all require a listener thread listening on one or more queues that receive all incoming messages / responses into the Ruby service, and then routing these messages to waiting threads using some message identifiers. This seems more complicated, and I am unable to use RabbitMQ for all the required semantic routing.

Is the first model a viable model for AMQP communication? Is there a better pattern for handling this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the answer largely depends on your use case

if you don't care about losing messages when a given queue is deleted, then the first option is fine.

if you need messages to stick around in a queue until something comes along to process it, then you need to have a durable queue where messages sit.

there is no requirement for queue per thread, with rabbitmq.

however, you should be using a channel per thread.

given that, you can have a channel per thread and have multiple channels consuming from the same (or different) queue without issue.

as long as you keep channels limited to a single thread, you can do whatever you need in regards to the queues you are consuming from.